PublicClientApplicationBuilder.AcquireTokenSilent throwing a MsalUiRequiredException 'Grant is expired'
Scenario
ASP.NET Core Web API is being called from a web app. The Web API being tasked with obtaining external users's grant Imap access to continuously read their email utilising MailKit.
This includes redirecting users to their email provider i.e. Google or Microsoft/Outlook/Exchange/Office365 authentication page.
Once the user signs in and provide the required consent to access their email, the Web Api app receives a credential which is being used to continuously monitor their email without further user intervention.
In case of Gmail, the credential obtained from the Authentication process is in form of a refresh token. This is being used to obtain access token when access token expires.
With Microsoft, the credential is in a form of a IAccount object.
For Microsoft there's also a Token Cache from where the necessary access token is being fetched by means of the above mentioned IAccount object.
With Gmail, I have got no problems. Everything runs smoothly.
However, with Microsoft it is a completely different story.
I manage so far to pass beyond the first step i.e. interactively getting the user to authenticate and grant access to their email. I am also able to use the obtained IAccount object credential to renew access silently (i.e. without user interaction). This works even when the app has stopped and re-started.
The big problem starts after 20 or so hours, When I get an MsalUiRequiredException 'Grant is expired'. Basically meaning that I have to get the user to go through the auth/grant/consent procedure all over again.
Here a some excerpts from the code I am using:
// Obtain (First stage) credentials interactively
var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(microsoftClientId)
        .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount)
        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
        .Build();

result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
       .WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions
        {
            HtmlMessageError = "<p> An error occurred: {0}. Details {1}</p>",
            BrowserRedirectSuccess = new Uri("https://xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx_thanks-for-consent-page")
        })
        .WithExtraHttpHeaders(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Origin", "http://localhost,https://localhost" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" } })
        .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
        .WithPrompt(Prompt.Consent)
        .ExecuteAsync(timerTokenSource.Token);

And this what I am using at a later stage (Like when the app re-started) to obtain the token silently.
refresh = await pca
    .AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account)
    .WithExtraHttpHeaders(new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Origin", "http://localhost,https://localhost" },
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" } })
    .WithTenantId("common")
    .ExecuteAsync();

account parameter being the account IAccount object obtained from the first phase and persisted.
Since I have control on the Token Cache persistence, I know for sure that the necessary token is being available for the above AcquireTokenSilent call.
And once again this technique will work fine for approx 20 hours, and after that it will fail with the dreaded MsalUiRequiredException.
Has anyone come across such?
Is there anything I am doing wrong?
Please do note: I do not want to go trough the Microsoft.Identity.Web route, as on the Web App (the one that uses this Web Api service) a user can in principle be logged in with other credentials then the email that he wants my Api to monitor. I want to be able to provide the user with a «Authorise Email Access» button instead of «sign-in» button.

That means the auth token has expired. You need to refresh it (which requires user interaction):
try {
    // First, check the cache for an auth token.
    return await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent (scopes, emailAddress).ExecuteAsync (cancellationToken);
} catch (MsalUiRequiredException) {
    // If that fails, then try getting an auth token interactively.
    return await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive (scopes).WithLoginHint (emailAddress).ExecuteAsync (cancellationToken);
}


The whole idea, is that I don't want any user interaction after successful consent obtained. I have included among the scopes 'offline_access'. The idea is, a user authentication should be invoked only once and then be able to act on it with further user intervention.

That might be the idea, but that's not how it works.

Well, I am trying now a whole different approach. The idea of 'long-living' silent access is definitely there.

You have got quite a few of commercial applications that you authenticate / consent once, and they are hooked on your emails forever.

I believe what you want is probably the Confidential Client workflow.

Thanks. Only small caveat is that a Confidential Client has not got a AcquireTokenInteractive method...
